# Retrieving documents by ids in a static list using ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I am having a hard time trying to solve a problem. The problem is something like this -

I have millions of documents in a type called `user` in ElasticSearch. There are two types of lists we create with these users.

1. Dynamic - Depending on the conditions the list members changes (for eg users which were created in last 30 days)
2. Static - The list of users is hardcoded with CSV of user id

We query both types of the list from ElasticSearch. A dynamic list is easier to query as it has fewer conditions to evaluate and ES does that pretty well. But the problem is retrieving data from the static list as the query is a `terms` query which has performance issues when the number of user ids are larger.

Following is my ES query

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms" : { "userId" : ["userId1", "userId2"]}
    }
}
```

If I pass multiple userId (of the order of 50k) ES CPU spikes up and starts giving 504 error.

Is there any alternative to storing static list where the data could be retrieved quickly from ES?

Comment: Can you provide full error log. 504 is very generic and does not give out anything important.

On the other not I think it is an issue of not enough resources. How is the cluster design (number of nodes/shards per index?).

Comment: @NashPL Basically the server is taking too long to respond. We can fix this by adding more resources. What I am looking for is the solution with the set of resources that I have currently. Terms query is not at all a solution

Comment: Cant build a car without a decent engine. Elastisearch have minimum requirement that you need to meet so the it works properly.
I would recommend getting more SWAP and RAM into a Node. More convoluted queries will slow it down even more without a decent hardware.

Comment: @NashPL Agreed. But, if you choose a better data structure than even with the same hardware performance can be achieved. I was trying to optimize on that part, upgrading hardware is always an option

Comment: As far I am aware Elasticsearch does not have much when it comes to amazing queries. I would recommend at this point to be more specific in the queries and provide as much information as you can.